# Login Parse via twitter with curl respond false

Tags: php, curl, twitter, parse-platform

I'm trying to implement login parse via twitter with curl, the guide in this link:
https://parse.com/docs/rest.html#users-signup

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: REMOVED" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: REMOVED" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
    "authData": {
      "twitter": {
        "id": "12345678",
        "screen_name": "ParseIt",
        "consumer_key": "REMOVED",
        "consumer_secret": "REMOVED",
        "auth_token": "REMOVED",
        "auth_token_secret": "REMOVED"
      }
    }
  }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/users
```

**And here is my implement code in PHP:**

```
$ci = curl_init();
$data = '{"authData":{"twitter":{"id":"REMOVED","screen_name":"cat",
"consumer_key":"REMOVED",
"consumer_secret":"REMOVED",
"auth_token":"REMOVED",
"auth_token_secret":"REMOVED"}}}';

$header = array("X-Parse-Application-Id: REMOVED",
"X-Parse-REST-API-Key: REMOVED",
"Content-Type: application/json"
);
curl_setopt ($ci, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ci,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($ci,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
curl_setopt($ci,CURLOPT_URL,'https://api.parse.com/1/users');
 $response = curl_exec($ci);
var_dump($response);    
curl_close($ci);
```

But the result of var_dump($response) is false.
I don't know what is wrong with my code. Can any body help me?

Comment: Note: as you've revealed you access tokens and secret keys, you may want to go to parse.com and invalidate them / get a new set.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

before you run the exec();

Process used to debug:

1. Before you `curl_close()`, use `print_r(curl_getinfo())`. This tells you everythign about your curl session.
2. You'll see that you get NOTHING back, which means firewall or other restriction in in place, or it's rejecting you for invalid headers.
3. So type URL into browser and see you need credentials. So the URL is correct, and it's not a firewall. Assume header is passing credentials (at this stage)
4. So then you notice it's SSL and you've not got the certificates for SSL. So that option above tells you to ignore certificate issues. That worked, stop here. (Otherwise chase down that credentials issue)

Comment: I've set the field curl_setopt($ci, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); as you know. I checked it isn't firewall. But I get the error: {"error":"unauthorized"}, I don't know what's wrong. Have you got any idea?

Comment: No idea, because it worked just fine for me. Check your API keys are all still valid - they may have expired?

Comment: I'm really stuck with this. Other function: register, login... still work. I'm sending feedback to parse.com. Hope they will help me soon.